# How does a digital camera measure white balance?

Tags: white-balance

Is there some kind of dedicated sensor for white balance in the camera, or does the processor just grab the normal image signal and perform some processing like "shift color to make the brightest part white"?

Comment: Have you looked at [how can color temperature be measured using a digital camera](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1997/how-can-color-temperature-be-measured-using-a-digital-camera) or [how white-balance really work](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5569/does-auto-white-balance-really-work-how) ?

Comment: The answers to that second question are extremely dated. A lot has changed since then.

Comment: @MichaelClark Sounds like a good time to provide an updated answer!